# Jetpack compose Switch() TrackWidth, TrackStrokeWidth, ThumbDiameter

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, uiswitch

Maybe someone can tell me how to set in Switch() size for TrackWidth, TrackStrokeWidth, ThumbDiameter

```
                Switch(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(end=16.dp),
                checked = auto.mainAuto.value,
                onCheckedChange = { auto.mainAuto.value = it },
                colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
                    checkedThumbColor = white_white,
                    checkedTrackColor = Accent_Blue,
                    uncheckedThumbColor = white_white,
                    uncheckedTrackColor = Disabled_Text,
                    ),
            )
```

Comment: Currently no way. You have to define your own custom Switch

Comment: Have you tried using `Modifier.scale(1.5f)`? it might help you achieve what you wish to if I am correct.

Comment: @JerryOkafor hi, ty for tip, but its not i'm looking for. Need to set ThumbDiameter smaller, and TrackWidth wider

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of Jetpack Compose 1.0.4, you **cannot change** them. But, the good news is that you can easily create any type of switch using Canvas API.

For example:

[image]
[image]

This is the code:

If you like it, I have made some [UI designs with Jetpack Compose](https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-samples/). Feel free to have a look at them.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateFloatAsState
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.scale
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.CornerRadius
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

/*
For more designs with source code, visit: https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-samples/
 */

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BlogPostsTheme(darkTheme = false) {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        Switch2()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Switch2(
    scale: Float = 2f,
    width: Dp = 36.dp,
    height: Dp = 20.dp,
    strokeWidth: Dp = 2.dp,
    checkedTrackColor: Color = Color(0xFF35898F),
    uncheckedTrackColor: Color = Color(0xFFe0e0e0),
    gapBetweenThumbAndTrackEdge: Dp = 4.dp
) {

    val switchON = remember {
        mutableStateOf(true) // Initially the switch is ON
    }

    val thumbRadius = (height / 2) - gapBetweenThumbAndTrackEdge

    // To move thumb, we need to calculate the position (along x axis)
    val animatePosition = animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (switchON.value)
            with(LocalDensity.current) { (width - thumbRadius - gapBetweenThumbAndTrackEdge).toPx() }
        else
            with(LocalDensity.current) { (thumbRadius + gapBetweenThumbAndTrackEdge).toPx() }
    )

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(width = width, height = height)
            .scale(scale = scale)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onTap = {
                        // This is called when the user taps on the canvas
                        switchON.value = !switchON.value
                    }
                )
            }
    ) {
        // Track
        drawRoundRect(
            color = if (switchON.value) checkedTrackColor else uncheckedTrackColor,
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(x = 10.dp.toPx(), y = 10.dp.toPx()),
            style = Stroke(width = strokeWidth.toPx())
        )

        // Thumb
        drawCircle(
            color = if (switchON.value) checkedTrackColor else uncheckedTrackColor,
            radius = thumbRadius.toPx(),
            center = Offset(
                x = animatePosition.value,
                y = size.height / 2
            )
        )
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(18.dp))

    Text(text = if (switchON.value) "ON" else "OFF")
}
```

### Edit:

Instead of `Canvas`, you can also use `Box`. [See this example](https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-custom-switch-button-icon/).

Answer (score 14):

Use `Modifier.scale(2f)`. Also add `Modifier.padding(20.dp)` as it is still measured by the default size.